# H2-database exception "Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_*" not found;" while running Junit test case

Tags: maven, junit, h2, spring-tool-suite

I am getting an error while executing junit test case, saying `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_BBAED672_9E78_4AC7_9306_10A675C3C8D2" not found; SQL statement`

I am working on a project `Project_Animal`, where I am using the entity class '`EntityAnimals`'.
I have another project `Project_Fruit` in the same workspace, where I am using the entity class '`EntityFruits`'.

I am getting below(logs) error for `EntityFruits` while running `Project_Animal` test cases.

I tried creating a new workspace and also reinstalling the STS. But it didn't work.

My queries 
1. what is the meaning of `CACHED` in h2-db -> `CREATE CACHED TABLE CAP.EntityFruits` 
2. Why is this happening only in my machine, same test cases pass successfully in other machines

Following is the stacktrace -

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290) [surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242) [surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121) [surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(ReflectionUtils.java:317) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.handleInvocationTargetException(ReflectionUtils.java:296) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(ReflectionUtils.java:280) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:219) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:472) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:370) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:229) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        ... 53 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_BBAED672_9E78_4AC7_9306_10A675C3C8D2" not found; SQL statement:
    CREATE CACHED TABLE CAP.EntityFruits(
    ENTITYFRUITSID INT DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR CAP.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_BBAED672_9E78_4AC7_9306_10A675C3C8D2) NOT NULL NULL_TO_DEFAULT SEQUENCE CAP.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_BBAED672_9E78_4AC7_9306_10A675C3C8D2,
    EFFECTIVETIMESTAMP VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    EXPIRATIONTIMESTAMP VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    RATING INT NOT NULL,
    ENTITYFRUITSID INT NOT NULL
) [90036-196])
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.schema.Schema.getSequence(Schema.java:517) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readSequence(Parser.java:5595) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:2891) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2390) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2377) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2347) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2178) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2150) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2142) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:2968) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2390) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2377) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2347) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2178) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2150) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2142) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:4035) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:6155) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4351) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:366) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:321) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepare(Parser.java:242) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepare(Session.java:543) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepare(Session.java:530) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.execute(MetaRecord.java:56) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:763) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:276) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:270) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:64) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:176) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        ... 74 common frames omitted
```

This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.animals</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws_animals</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ws_animals</name>
    <description>Animals Details</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <!-- Below properties are higher version when compared to the parent pom -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mssql-jdbc.version>6.1.0.jre8</mssql-jdbc.version> <!-- 6.1.0.jre7 is available in the parent pom -->
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version> <!-- 5.0.11 is available in the parent pom -->


        <!-- Below properties are not available in the parent pom -->
        <camel.core.version>2.19.0</camel.core.version>
        <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory>
        <skip-integration-tests>false</skip-integration-tests>
        <camel.core.version>2.19.0</camel.core.version>
        <wiremock.standalone.version>2.5.1</wiremock.standalone.version>

        <!-- Correct Version -->
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>

        <!-- Sonar exclusions -->

        <!-- RestDocs -->
        <restDocDirectory>docs</restDocDirectory>
        <restDocName>index</restDocName>
        <restDocExtension>.html</restDocExtension>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Dependencies List Starting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-restassured</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ORM Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing Dependencies List Starting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>    

        <!-- H2 Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing Dependencies List Ending -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>${wiremock.standalone.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>               
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my yaml file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ws_animals
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
      naming:
       physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    database: SQL_SERVER
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
datasource:
    maxTotal: 10
    maxActive: 10
    initial-size: 1
    test-on-borrow: false
    test-while-idle: true
    time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 60000
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    validation-query: SELECT 1
    url: jdbc:h2:~/account;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init.sql'
```

Comment: What tool are you using for the build? Can you add the build file (pom.xml or build.gradle)?

Comment: I am using maven for build

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Sequence "SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_BBAED672_9E78_4AC7_9306_10A675C3C8D2" not found; Do you have this sequence defined in database?

Comment: Plz check the updated post.

Comment: @AnilBachola how to find the sequence in h2Database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

In my **YML** file, I have Datasource url as **`url: jdbc:h2:~/account;`**

So it was storing the ***cached data*** for h2Database in **`account.db, account.mv`**, etc.(files with **`.db`** extension) files in my user directory(**`~`**).

These files were corrupted while executing **`Fruit_Project`** test cases.

Since the Datasource url was same for both the projects, it was affecting my other project. Hence, changing workspace did not help.

Solution - 
 
1. I **deleted** these files, and boom, all junit test cases started executing. 
 
or
 
2. Change the datasource url -> **`url: jdbc:h2:~/some_other_name;`**

Comment: Thanks, I had similar issue and removing `.db` files helped!